# How can I generate a dynamic PassphraseKey for the EncryptedStore instead of being hardcoded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, dynamic, encryption

I am trying to secure my sqlite db by encrypting it,everything is ok with encryption unless I need to use a dynamic key instead of the hard coded one,any ideas how to generate this key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of encryption method are you using? Anyway, you could generate a key using hash function like md5 or sha256

here the md5 function

```
-(NSString*) getMD5fromString:(NSString*)baseString
{
    if ([self isNull:baseString])
        return nil;

    const char *cStr = [baseString UTF8String];

    unsigned char resultChar[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_MD5( cStr, (CC_LONG)strlen(cStr), resultChar);
    NSString *md5 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
                     resultChar[0], resultChar[1], resultChar[2], resultChar[3],
                     resultChar[4], resultChar[5], resultChar[6], resultChar[7],
                     resultChar[8], resultChar[9], resultChar[10], resultChar[11],
                     resultChar[12], resultChar[13], resultChar[14], resultChar[15]];
    return  md5;
}
```

here the sha256 function

```
-(NSString*)getSHA256fromString:(NSString*)baseString
{
    const char* str = [baseString UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(str, (unsigned int)strlen(str), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

For example you could generate your encryption / decryption key in this way:

```
NSString* cipherKey = [self getMD5fromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",self.loggedUserUuid,self.localMachineName]];
```

In this way you have a generated key vaild for that user on that device

Hope it helps!

Comment: thnx Luca,Actually I did something similar to that and it works fine,so this solution looks working too